# Cannot define FastReport query parameters, must declare scalar variable error

Tags: .net, sql-server, fastreport

I have been trying to add a data source to my FastReport Report. I have followed the instructions inside the software documentation closely but somehow it doesn't work. I am using SQL Server and I am trying to use a stored procedure as a data source.

Below is the code and screenshot of what I tried to do.
[image: Trying to add a parameter through the Query wizard]
[image: The error I keep getting]
and this is the code if you can't open up the image:

```sql
exec WebApp.dbo.eos_ReversPodaci @ID
```

[FastReport using stored procedures](https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/show/stored-procedures-net/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this issue. First create a query with no parameters like `select 1` and add the parameters you plan on using, then edit the query and insert the one you actually plan on using with all the parameters you defined in the previous step. It's a hassle but it works.